# Regex - Negating two patterns

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-negation

I searched for an answer to this but can't seem to make it work.

I have a string which is : INTRA\ABC00

I want to replace everything except ABC00 which is always 3 letters, 2 numbers.

I'm trying:

```
-replace "[?!A-Za-z]{3}[?!0-9]{2}" 

-replace "[^A-Za-z]{3}[^0-9]{2}"
```

But it doesn't work. I'm new at regex so thanks for your help! I hope it's not a duplicate, I searched and couldn't find an answer for a case like this.

**EDIT: Regarding the duplicate flag : I know I can grab what is after the backslash but I want a way to replace everything but 3 letters 2 digits since I would use that pattern in other instances for example where I have a string like "fsdjkjABC00fsdjkk"**

Comment: Try `"INTRA\ABC00" -replace '^.*\\(.*)','$1'`.

Comment: This work but what if I want to do specifically what is asked in the question, replace all but AAA00 ? For example If i had this string : "f3f2sdABC00fj3kj3" I would need a way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: `-replace '.*\\.*?([a-z]{3}\d{2}).*', '$1'`